# Eliminate whitespace between divs generated from loop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a Razor page that I'm attempting to show `<div>` elements in rows using Bootstrap. Each `<div>` is generated programmatically like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-4">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
}
```

My problem is that there's whitespace or a return character or something between each `<div>` and that causes the last `<div>` to get pushed to the next line.

So with `class="col-4"`, I *should* be able to squeeze 3 elements onto one row. But the third one gets pushed to the next row. Typically, when I hardcode this sort of thing, I remove all whitespace between each `<div>` and it fixes the issue:

```
<!-- THIS WORKS -->
<div class="col-4">
    <!-- content -->
</div><div class="col-4">
    <!-- content -->
</div><div class="col-4">
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<!-- THIS DOESN'T WORK -->
<div class="col-4">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

My question is **how do I achieve this when I'm rendering each div programmatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are within a bootstrap `row` and just using `col-*` elements then whitespace should not matter at all.  Your code sample has some missing quotes which could be screwing things up, but I can't tell if that's a typo in your question or the actual code output.

When the quotes are fixed and put into a `row` I don't see any issues at all or even any differences between the two code samples you provided

```css
div[class^="col-"]{
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <!-- THIS WORKS -->
  <div class="col-4">
      1
  </div><div class="col-4">
      2
  </div><div class="col-4">
      3
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="row">
  <!-- THIS DOESN'T WORK -->
  <div class="col-4">
      1
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
      2
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
      3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is adding more elements than the 3 that will fit on a row with `col-4` an issue if I wrap them in a `<div class="row">`?

Comment: I was under the impression that I should only have a single row's worth of content inside that row div. This may be my issue.

Comment: Yep, that was my issue. I needed to wrap the columns in a `row` div.

Comment: @TheIronCheek Read up on what a row is and how the grid system works in [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/). A `col-*` element may only exsit inside a `row`, and a `row` may only contain `col-*` as direct children. You are allowed 12 "slots" in a row. The above example has 3 columns taking up 4 each. 3x4=12. You could have 2x `col-6` elements, or 4 `col-3` elements for example.  If you add elements that add up to more than 12, they simply wrap to the next line. For example 6 `col-4` elements will display as two lines with 3 columns each.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, is there a good reason why you're wanting to specify the column widths if generating the column divs in a loop? By using the `col-4` class you're limited to only looping over 3 items every time (unless you modify the default `$grid-columns` setting to be larger than 12, of course), and as you're obstensibly expecting these divs in this example to be equal-width, **you may as well just use `col` instead and let the divs auto-format**.

Doing so should keep all elements on the same row:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I wouldn't think that whitespace/newline should make any difference... but it does sound like it's behaving as if the aggregated column widths exceed the max grid columns, even though that shouldn't be the case (again, assuming that the default `$grid-columns` Sass variable value hasn't been reduced).

Alternatively (or additionally), you can try using the inline flex display class for the container, like so:

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex flex-row">
 <div class="col">
   <!-- content -->
 </div>
 <div class="col">
   <!-- content -->
 </div>
 <div class="col">
   <!-- content -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I defined the width and used `col-4` because I specifically want only 3 per row. Additional elements should wrap to the next line.